# instanceof Class<?> parameter

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm trying to write a method to return all objects that match the class it gets as a parameter:

```
public class Scenario extends View {

    ...

    private Actor[] actors = new Actor[1024];

    ...

    public Actor[] getActors(Class<?> cls) {
        //Count actors corresponding to class cls
        int cnt = 0;      
        for (int i = 0; i<actorsCount; i++)
           if (actors[i] instanceof cls) cnt++; 


        //Build a new array;
        Actor[] clsActors = new Actor[cnt];

        //Fill it
        for (int j = 0, k=0; j<cnt; k++)
           if (actors[k] instanceof cls)
              clsActors[j++] = actors[k];

        return clsActors;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error: **"- Incompatible operand types boolean and Class＜capture#1-of ? extends Scenario＞"**

'Actor' is extended by my sprites, say Bird, Hero, etc.
The idea is, for example, to get a list of all Birds on the Scenario at a given time for some calculations.

Any idea what's going on here? How to test if a given object is an instance of a given class?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    static class Actor {}
    static class Frog extends Actor {@Override public String toString() {return "I'm a frog";}}
    static class Lizard extends Actor {@Override public String toString() {return "I'm a lizard";}}

        private static Actor[] actors;        

        public static Actor[] getActors(Class<?> cls) {
            //Count actors corresponding to class cls
            int cnt = 0;      
            for (int i = 0; i<actors.length; i++)
               if (cls.isInstance(actors[i])) cnt++; 

            //Build a new array;
            Actor[] clsActors = new Actor[cnt];

            //Fill it
            for (int j = 0, k=0; j<cnt; k++)
                    if (cls.isInstance(actors[k]))
                  clsActors[j++] = actors[k];

            return clsActors;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            actors = new Actor[] {new Frog(), new Lizard()};
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getActors(Frog.class)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[I'm a frog]
```

Edit: More elegant version of getActors() using a List:

```
    public static Actor[] getActors(Class<?> cls) {
        LinkedList<Actor> chosenActors = new LinkedList<Actor>();           
        for(Actor actor: actors) if(cls.isInstance(actor)) chosenActors.add(actor);                         
        return chosenActors.toArray(new Actor[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write an example.

Comment: You're welcome! If you use this example in production code I would however think about using a list as a return type or temporary variable because it's easy to make mistakes with the loop indices.

Comment: It indeed looks more elegant using collections as you say, actually the whole Scenario mechanic worked using collections before. *I made it ugly*, because Collections allocate stuff (Iterators) and I need this actor arrays for a render loop. I finished implementing it by now and I got rid of tons of GC_FOR_MALLOC events. It's a pity because the code used to look wonderful using ArrayLists... (I didn't mention it before but this is an android app, so targeted to low specs devices)

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
cls.isInstance(yourObject)
```

instead of using the `instanceof` operator, which can only be used if you know the class at compile time.

Comment: Thank you very much!, any idea about the impact in performance of the usage of the isInstance method?

Comment: It won't be slower than `instanceof`, most likely.

Answer (score 6):

`instanceof` can only be used with class literals. You need to use [`Class.isInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29), i.e

```
if (cls.isInstance(actors[k]))
```